# Iteration algorithm in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to find and print that how many num of bob in a string with the following program but it isn't working. Can anyone tell what is wrong with it?

```
s='bob123 bob bob 3434'
num=0
a=0
b=3
for char in s:
    if s[a:b]=='bob':
        num+=1
        a+=1
        b+=2
print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s='bob123 bob bob 3434'
print(s.count("bob"))
```

You can count how many `bob` occurences are they in your string.

[**repl.it working**](https://repl.it/ImaP/0)

Comment: Ok, i can count that way but I want to know that what is wrong with that code.Means what is algorithmically wrong with that code. @zooly

Comment: As said hiro (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44562439/4781975), you need to iterate in all cases. With your current indent, you increase a & b only when you find an occurence in the string

Answer (score 0):

what is not working is that your indentation is off: you need to increase `a` and `b` also if the string is not found; and both need to be increased by `1` only (you increase `b` by `2`):

```
for char in s:
    if s[a:b]=='bob':
        num+=1
    a+=1
    b+=1
```

a slightly more pythonic way to do this might be:

```
num = 0
for i in range(len(s)+1-3):
    if s[i:i+3] == 'bob':
        num+=1
```

the [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=.count#str.count) method of string would be the much better version for this:

```
s.count('bob')
```